# Adobe Reader COM Component

Tags: c#, printing, adobe, reader

I want to use the adobe reader com component to view pdf and print on the selected printer. unfortunately I can not find a command. It is only possible to print on the default printer or open the print window.

```
axAcroPDF1.printAll();
or
axAcroPDF1.printWithDialog();
```

Comment: [Adobe forum post with same question](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2220589)

Comment: and some free method? no additional libraries?